# How to create a login page for a user that checks their password on the client side

Tags: javascript, html

How do I create a login page that checks for a correct password on the client side and goes to the next screen if the password is correct?

Here is my attempt:

```html
<html>
<p> Enter Username and Password </p>
<FORM action="file:///android_asset/www/Browse.html" method="post">
    <P>
    <LABEL for="firstname">Username </LABEL>
              <INPUT type="text" id="Username"><BR>
    <LABEL for="lastname">Password </LABEL>
              <INPUT type="text" id="Password"><BR>
        <INPUT type="submit" value="Send"> <INPUT type="reset">
    </P>
 </FORM>
</html>
```

Comment: You have misconception about HTML. HTML is Hypertext Markup Language which is suited for web page structure definition not for any logic such as you want. What research have you done before asking?

Comment: Just to be clearer, since newbies might see this old question and not realize what's at stake: if you put a check for the password in plain HTML, then anyone who can read HTML will know the password, because it will be hardcoded in the page (the HTML or Javascript can be inspected on the fly by any browser). You *must* use something else than HTML (for example, PHP), something that only your server has access, and not the user that receives the HTML page. For this reason, this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11930310/4621141 is useless. For anyone can always read `"mypaswrd"`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Simple Login Page</h1>
        <form name="login">
            Username<input type="text" name="userid"/>
            Password<input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
            <input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
            <input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
        </form>
        <script language="javascript">
            function check(form) { /*function to check userid & password*/
                /*the following code checkes whether the entered userid and password are matching*/
                if(form.userid.value == "myuserid" && form.pswrd.value == "mypswrd") {
                    window.open('target.html')/*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
                }
                else {
                    alert("Error Password or Username")/*displays error message*/
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: any username and password should match? how can i achieve this(not myuserid and mypswrd)

Comment: replace: 

`if(form.userid.value == "myuserid" && form.pswrd.value == "mypswrd")`

with

`if(form.userid.value == form.pswrd.value)`

Comment: hi i created a button called savedata <input type="submit" onclick="check(this.form)" value=" SaveData "/> but it is not doing anything

Comment: <html>
 select the File
</br>
<form name="save">
<p>
 <input type="file" id="uploader" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value=" SaveData "/>
<input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
</p>

</html>

Comment: Snippets of this answer show up in an amusingly large amount of code on Github: https://github.com/search?q=%22the+following+code+checkes+whether+the+entered+userid+and+password+are+matching%22&type=Code

Answer (score 3):

Doing password checks on client side is unsafe especially when the password is hard coded.

The safest way is password checking on server side, but even then the password should not be transmitted plain text.

Checking the password client side is possible in a "secure way":

- The password needs to be hashed
- The hashed password is used as part of a new url

Say "abc" is your password so your md5 would be "900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72" (consider [salting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography))!). Now build a url containing the hash (like http://yourdomain.com/90015...f72.html).